# Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode facing error during execution

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am getting an error in my Go code import statements. I am attaching the code and the error I got in vscode. Kindly help me to identify the issue. I think there is some problem with my Go installation so I am also providing a screenshot of exception which I am getting while opening the Ubuntu on my VM. Please help me to rectify this exception as well. Many thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of things, there's a syntax error in your .profile on line 21. This looks to be attempting to add the /usr/local/go/bin to your PATH possibly? This might explain things since the go executables are not on your PATH.

First, make sure Go is installed in /usr/local/go:

```
$ ls /usr/local/go
AUTHORS     LICENSE     VERSION     blog        lib     robots.txt
CONTRIBUTING.md PATENTS     api     doc     misc        src
CONTRIBUTORS    README.md   bin     favicon.ico pkg     test
```

If running ls /usr/local/go returns the same output as above, then you should
have something like the following in your ~/.profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:.
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for helping me, I have followed what you mentioned and the first step is giving me the same output which you posted and my profile has below entries. 

PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"




export PATH=$PATH: /usr/local/go/bin


export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin


export PATH=$PATH: /usr/local/go/bin


export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

I think somehow I messed my Go user profiles by following multiple sources. So can you have a look at the attached image and let me know what can be done as next steps.

Comment: When you run 'ls /usr/local/go' what response do you get?

Comment: I am getting this 

sam@sam-VirtualBox:~$ ls /usr/local/go
api      bin   CONTRIBUTING.md  doc          lib      misc     pkg        robots.txt  test     AUTHORS  blog  CONTRIBUTORS     favicon.ico  LICENSE  PATENTS  README.md  src         VERSION

Comment: anyways that Go error is now gone as I have installed some prerequisites using VScode. Sorry for your time Chris but now I am getting below error while running the docker-compose-simple.yaml file from chaincode-docker-devmode path. Here is the error description-------------------------

orderer      | 2018-06-30 12:17:03.129 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 16a Error reading from 172.20.0.5:52564: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
orderer      | 2018-06-30 12:17:03.129 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 16b Closing Deliver stream

Comment: Hope below warning description also helps--------------
orderer      | 2018-06-30 12:17:02.810 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 167 Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/Consortium
orderer      | 2018-06-30 12:17:02.911 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 168 [channel: myc] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.20.0.5:52566 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group]  /Channel/Application at version 0, but got version 1

Comment: I was looking at the documents and it seems like the upgrade process mentions three Groups namely Application, Orderer, and Channel. If you see the error description it ends on checking version comparison within Groups Channel and Application. Maybe this can help you to narrow down the problem.